# How can I set SO_REUSEPORT on the socket

Tags: c++, sockets, network-programming, boost-asio, systemd

How can I modify the `server_http.hpp` file in the Http Server Library to set `SO_REUSEPORT` on the socket? Or how can I pass in a fd. (the systemd .socket file will need ReusePort=yes for that).

https://github.com/eidheim/Simple-Web-Server/blob/master/server_http.hpp

Answer (score 2):

SO_REUSEPORT doesn't exist in Windows, so there is only system-dependent solution:

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>

/// ... 
int opt = 1;
::setsockopt(acceptor.native_handle(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &opt, sizeof(opt));
```

But in general, I think you should ask yourself, why do you need it?

Comment: @islandslangz then don't you need to use the socket that systemd transferred to you?

Comment: I see. It's not clear from your code that you want to use the same socket. In that case you should add in your systemd.service file, in `Service` section line `StandardInput=socket`. In that case systemd will start your service and provide you fd as argument. You can call `socket.assign()` to assign that fd to your boost socket.